# Laravel-Backpack - How to re-render Ajax charts

Tags: ajax, laravel, charts, chart.js, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to display some AJAX loaded charts that change content when the user changes a filter without reloading the page. Followed Backpack and Laravel charts docs but I'm kinda stuck on how to re-render the chart without reloading the page. This is what I have so far:

routes:

```
    Route::get('charts/test-chart', 'Charts\TestChartChartController@response')->name('charts.test-chart.index');
    Route::get('charts/test-chart-ajax', 'Charts\TestChartChartController@data');
```

controller:

```
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->chart = new Chart();

        $labels = [];
        
        for ($days_backwards = 30; $days_backwards >= 0; $days_backwards--) {
            if ($days_backwards == 1) {
            }
            $labels[] = $days_backwards.' days ago';
        }
        $this->chart->labels($labels);

        $this->chart->load(backpack_url('charts/test-chart-ajax'));
    }

    public function data(Request $request)
    {
        for ($days_backwards = 30; $days_backwards >= 0; $days_backwards--) {
            $users[] = \App\Models\User::whereDate('created_at', today()
                ->subDays($days_backwards))
                ->count();
        }

        $this->chart->dataset('Users', 'line', $users)
            ->color('rgb(77, 189, 116)')
            ->backgroundColor('rgba(77, 189, 116, 0.4)');

        return $this->chart->api();
    }
```

view:

```
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

@php
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

@php
    Widget::add([
    'type'     => 'event_select',
    'view'     => 'event_select',
    ]);

    Widget::add(
    [
        'type'    => 'div',
        'class'   => 'row',
        'content' => [ // widgets 
            [ 'type'=> 'chart', 'controller' => \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Charts\TestChartChartController::class ],
        ]
    ]);

@endphp

@section('content')
@endsection
```

js: (here is the part where I'm lost)

```
@push('after_scripts')
    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.eventSelector').each(function(index, element) {
            selected_event = this.getAttribute('selected_event');
            this.value = selected_event;
        });

        $('.eventSelector').on('change', changeType); 
    }); 

    function changeType() {
        
        var eventId = $('.eventSelector').val(); 

        $.ajax(
        {
           This is the part where I'm stuck, I don't know how to make the ajax call to reload the chart without reloading the page.
        });    
    }
    
    </script>
@endpush
```

It works alright the first time but I don't really know how to re-render the chart when the user changes the filter. Apparently there is something in the docs here : https://v6.charts.erik.cat/api_charts.html#update-the-chart-after-rendering but I have no idea how to use that api_url mentioned. At the end of the documentation there is a link to a sample, but now seems broken (404)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

***EDIT: I think I made some progress, but now I get an error I haven't been able to solve:
I added this to the script.blade.js file and it looks like its refreshing the table (because my endpoint is getting called twice):

```
        var original_api_url = {{ $chart->id }}_api_url;

        {{ $chart->id }}_refresh(original_api_url + "?year=22");
```

But I get this error on the console:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'datasets')

Comment: Link you posted in your question to the update page shows fine to me

Comment: Yeah that link is fine. I'm talking about another link at the end of that documentation that had a sample. Let me edit my question because my wording was confusing at best. Thanks.